# cmake and "CMakeLists.txt" files inheritance

Tags: path, cmake

I have this problem with cmake:

In the top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(MY_INCLUDE_DIR "/path/to/dir")
```

In the lower level CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(${MY_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

GCC, through the make command, returns a "No such file or directory" relative to the line that includes the file located in `MY_INCLUDE_DIR`.
However, if I move the set line in the same lower level file where I specify the include directories, everything is fine.

In the documentation it is clearly written that lower level files inherit what is in the higher level ones.

What is wrong in my files?

Thank's.

Comment: Have you done ``add_subdirectory`` after setting ``MY_INCLUDE_DIR``?

Comment: Is /path/to/dir a relative or an absolute path?

Comment: @sakra: it is an absolute path.

Comment: From what I know directories specified in `include_directory` are relative to `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`, so try setting the variable to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${MY_INCLUDE_DIR}`

Comment: Are you `set()`ing your var before `add_subdirectory()` call?